# Not able to access Kibana when Elasticsearch and Kibana are setup on different servers with search guard

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

I am trying to setup an `ES` cluster and `Kibana` on different VMs. The `ES` cluster is setup and secured with `search-guard`, I can even access it from the browser and `curl`.

I've setup `kibana` on an other VM and changed the `elasticsearch.url` to one of the servers of the `ES` cluster, and I've also updated the `elasticsearch.username` and `elasticsearch.password`.

Since I am using a self-signed `SSL` i've set the following as well.

`elasticsearch.ssl.verificationMode: none`

The firewall is allowed for port `5601` and the logs are as below but i still am not able to access `kibana`. Should i install `kibana` on an `ES Node` for it to work or how?

```
Nov 07 02:55:42 Kibana systemd[1]: Started Kibana.
Nov 07 02:56:09 Kibana kibana[25483]: {"type":"log","@timestamp":"2018-11-07T02:56:09Z","tags":["info","optimize"],"pid":25483,"message":"Optimizing and caching bundles for ml, stateSessionStorageRedirect, status_page, timelion, graph, monitoring, dashboardViewer, apm and kibana. This may take a few minutes"}
```

Comment: Couple of things to check: 1) Is server.host setting in kibana.yml configured to listen on all interfaces i.e. server.host: 0.0.0.0 ? 2) Is Kibana up & running ? 3) Are you able to curl localhost:5601 from Kibana VM ?

Comment: @ben5556 Solved it, Thanks.
The `server.host` was `localhost`. Created an `nginx` reverse proxy and connected it via that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set `server.host: 0.0.0.0` in kibana.yml to listen on all interfaces